# Is it possible to use the Like Button Social plugin to like a feed from a landing page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I have a Facebook feed that takes me to a landing page when I click on it. I want to be able to add Facebook's like plugin onto that landing page in order to like the feed I came from. This would be the equivalent of clicking like from the feed post itself. I don't know what  to use for the data-href property in order to connect the like button to the feed.

I know the feed id and access_token and have tried the following:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1608072154_362229823788663&access_token=...
http://www.facebook.com/1608072154/posts/362229823788663
```

So far I've only been able to like link urls and not the actual feed post.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? and if so, how do I get the url?

Answer (score 0):

> Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Yes it is possible, but not with the like plugin.  I have a production app that pulls in a person's feed from multiple social networks including Facebook.  I display a gray star for unliked content and a gold star for liked items.  When the user clicks the gray star for a facebook item, I send an HTTP Post to the Graph API with `/post_id/likes` which likes it.  If they click the gold star, then I send an HTTP DELETE to the `/post_id/likes` which removes it.  See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ and the "likes" create/delete section near the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get a like button working using the graph api as you suggested. I was hoping to be able to use the plugin so that I could get the additional functionality the plugin offers for free (friend images, etc.), but it looks like I'll have to do my own implementation using the graph api. Sigh... Oh well.

Comment: Glad to assist.  Happy coding!